How should I install xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe for Ubuntu 22.04?
I use multiple TrackPoints and I must switch from libinput to evdev for usability reasons. When I install xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04, middle-button scrolling doesn't work (but all of the other requirements are met). When I install xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04, middle-button scrolling works just fine, but drag selections (where you hold the left mouse button and drag to select text) doesn't work.
So how should I install xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe for Ubuntu 22.04 such that it all works? I would very much appreciate any help.
For completeness, I'll give some more details below.
To install xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04, I took the following approach:
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
reboot

Then, to install xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04, I took the following approach:
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04
wget https://ubuntu.mirror.root.lu/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04/xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04_2.10.5-1ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04_2.10.5-1ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb
reboot


Did you try the xserver-xorg-input-evdev package?

I'm really not sure if this makes sense, but maybe it's worth a shot : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/741772

@ubfan1 Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I've tried that. The package xserver-xorg-input-evdev results in the same behaviour with the package xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04, with middle-button scrolling not working.

Maybe compare the two packages' /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf file and see how they differ. Maybe a copy/edit will get all the capabilities into one file.
See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274149/setting-up-xorg-input-devices-without-udev for  replacing udev daemon with explicit devices.
